# Post request sends undefined data inn flutter app

Tags: node.js, dart, flutter

I was working on a simple app with login functionality , but im unable to send username and password properly to nodejs server. I have tried encoding it, putting it as Map and FormData, but nothing seems to workout. I console logged the request body and it prints "undefind"

I'm using Dio dart package for making http requests and Redux and redux thunk to dispatch actions .
//Code on My flutter app

```
    ThunkAction<AppState> login(LoginData data) {
          return (Store<AppState> store) async {
            store.dispatch(IsLoading(true));

            try {
              Response response = await Dio().post(
                  "http://10.0.2.2:4000/api/user/login",
                  data: json.encode({"phone": data.phone, "password": data.password}));

              if (response.statusCode == 200) {
                print(json.decode(response.data));
                store.dispatch(IsLoading(false));
              }
            } catch (e) {
              print("Error :(");
            }
          };
        }

// Code on My nodejs 


    router.post("/login", (req, res) => {
    //this log prints undefined
      console.log("Login route: " + req.body.phone);
      var cred = {
        phone: req.body.phone,
        password: req.body.password
      };

      User.findOne({ phone: cred.phone })
        .then(result => {
          if (!result) {
            res.status(400).json({ msg: "no user" });
          } else {
            bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, result.password, (err, isMatch) => {
              if (isMatch) {
                const payload = { id: result._id };
                console.log("Logged in :" + payload);
                jwt.sign(
                  payload,
                  keys.secretOrKey,
                  { expiresIn: 7200 },
                  (err, token) => {
                    res.status(200).json({
                      success: true,
                      token: "Bearer " + token
                    });
                  }
                );
              } else {
                res.status(400).json({ msg: err });
              }
            });
          }
        })
        .catch(err => {
          res.status(400).json({ msg: err });
        });
    });
```

Comment: I had the same problem and was solved by adding `HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded` header to my request

Comment: Thanks a lot its working :)

Comment: @Saman, you can add this as an answer rather than a comment since it solved the poster's problem.

Answer (score 2):

To access parameter in server side add this header to you request:

```
HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
```